# Select Sub query - based on value

Tags: sql, oracle

Need help in creating subquery.

I have two tables "Department Access Info" & "Subject Code Master Table" . Need to combine these tables in case if any Dept_code has access value as "ALL". Below is the sample information.

**Department Access Info Table** Input with Subject_Code as "ALL"

| Dept_Code | Subject_Code |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | aa1 |
| 102 | **ALL** |
| 103 | cc1 |

In case there is Subject code with "ALL", then  we need to refer Subject code specific table to get all subjects. For example for Dept_Code "102" has access to "ALL" subjects.

Input Type -2 with Dept_Code as 'ALL' and Subject_Code as 'ALL'

| Dept_Code | Subject_Code |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | aa1 |
| 102 | **ALL** |
| 103 | cc1 |
| **ALL** | **ALL** |

There is Dept_Code_Master Table with all Dep_Codes
|Dept_Code|
|---------|
|101      |
|102      |
|103      |
|104      |

**Subject Code Master Table**

| Dept_Code | Subject_Code |
| --- | --- |
| 102 | bb1 |
| 102 | bb2 |
| 102 | bb3 |
| 104 | dd1 |

By Combining 101 , 102 & 103 department code final required result as follows:

**Final Required Output:** for Type-1 Input

| Dept_Code | Subject_Code |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | aa1 |
| 102 | bb1 |
| 102 | bb2 |
| 102 | bb3 |
| 103 | cc1 |

Final Required Output : Type 2 Input (ALL COMPANY, ALL ACCOUNT)

| Dept_Code | Subject_Code |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | aa1 |
| 102 | bb1 |
| 102 | bb2 |
| 102 | bb3 |
| 103 | cc1 |
| 104 | dd1 |

**** Edited with Input2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just outer join, is it not?

```
SQL> select a.dept_code,
  2    case when a.subject_code = 'ALL' then b.subject_code
  3         else a.subject_code
  4    end subject_code
  5  from code_master a left join subject_code_master b on a.dept_code = b.dept_code
  6  order by 1, 2;

DEPT_CODE  SUBJECT_CODE
---------- ---------------
101        aa1
102        bb1
102        bb2
102        bb3
103        cc1

SQL>
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks !!!  Have one more condition with Dept_Code with "ALL" and  Subject_Code with "ALL" Values. Need to execute different Select query in case both are "ALL" value. How we can modify?

Comment: You're welcome. I don't understand what you asked. As there's no WHERE clause in my query, you don't have to do anything. If that's not so, maybe you should edit the question and explain - **with examples** what you meant.

Comment: Edited requirement with type-2 Input and Output. Please refer above

Answer (score 0):

With the example you've provided it doesn't look like a subquery is necessary.

```
WITH CODE_MASTER AS
  ( SELECT '101' AS Dept_code,
           'aa1' AS Subject_Code
      FROM dual
      UNION
     SELECT '102' AS Dept_code,
           'All' AS Subject_Code
      FROM dual
      UNION
     SELECT '103' AS Dept_code,
           'cc2' AS Subject_Code
      FROM dual
  ),
SUBJECT_CODE_MASTER AS
  ( SELECT '102' AS Dept_code,
           'bb1' AS Subject_Code
      FROM dual
      UNION
     SELECT '102' AS Dept_code,
           'bb2' AS Subject_Code
      FROM dual
      UNION
     SELECT '102' AS Dept_code,
           'bb3' AS Subject_Code
      FROM dual
  )
SELECT CODE_MASTER.DEPT_CODE,
       COALESCE(SUBJECT_CODE_MASTER.subject_code, CODE_MASTER.subject_code) AS Subject_Code
  FROM CODE_MASTER 
  LEFT
  JOIN SUBJECT_CODE_MASTER
    ON CODE_MASTER.dept_code = SUBJECT_CODE_MASTER.dept_code
   AND CODE_MASTER.Subject_Code = 'All'
```

Comment: Thanks for giving solution . In case if i have more than 1000 line values, do we need to do "UNION" for all values. And in case if both Dept_Code and Subject_Code is "All", need to execute select query from another table. How to go ahead

Comment: @Db_Learner That clause just reproduces your sample data. It isn't actually part of the query.